# Use where getcurrent date and datetime 00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this current query:

```
select t1.itemcode as ItemCode, t1.CodeBars as CodeBars, t1.ItemName as ItemName, t0.price as Price, t1.UpdateDate, t1.UpdateTS
from ITM9 T0
inner join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode
inner join ouom t2 on t2.uomentry = t0.uomentry where Cast(t1.UpdateDate As Time) = '00:00:00.0000000'
```

[image]

with these results, I would like only search items with UpdateDate = Todaysdate and 00:00... for example where UpdateDate = 2020-11-25 00:00:00.000 if I run the query tomorrow should search for 2020-11-26 00:00:00.000 and so on.

I'm confused on how to achieve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just convert the `updatedate` and `getdate()` to dates and compare:

```
where convert(date, updatedate) = convert(date, getdate())
```

If you have other times and specifically want midnight, you can also include:

```
where convert(date, updatedate) = convert(date, getdate()) and
      updatedate = convert(date, updatedate)
```